# Converting List Comprehensions to For Loops in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array, list-comprehension

I understand the importance of list comprehensions, but do not understand their inner-workings, thus am not able to understand them in simpler terms such as I would a for loop. For example, how could I change this to a for loop:

```
li = [row[index] for row in outer_list]
```

In this example I have a list of lists, for my purposes a matrix, called **outer_list** which is a list of lists. The **index** value is the column number the outer iteration is at, from 0 to some number n. The list comprehension above returns the **index**'th column in the matrix, and assigns it to **li** as a list. How can I create a for loop that creates a list in this manner?

Answer (score 8):

It's just a shorter way of expressing a `list`.

```
li = [row[index] for row in outer_list]
```

is equivalent to:

```
li = []
for row in outer_list:
    li.append(row[index])
```

Once you get used to the syntax, it becomes a tidy way of creating `list`s (and other iterables).

Answer (score 0):

### Question:

> How could I change this to a for loop?

```
li = [row[index] for row in outer_list]
```

### Answer:

```
li = []
for row in outer_list:
   li.append(row[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the outer iteration is for the index, this code can be effectively re-written as :

```
for row in outer_list:
    li.append(row[index])
```

Here you are iterating in the lists inside the `outer_list`. So, the first iteration would add the first list inside `outer_list` to `li`, then the second one is appended and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to imply that this snippet is already inside of a for loop, like this:

```
outer_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

for index in xrange(3):
    li = [row[index] for row in outer_list]
    print li
```

which would output:

```
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```

You could convert this to use only conventional `for` loops by nesting an inner loop inside of your outer loop:

```
outer_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

for index in xrange(3):
    li = []                    # initial empty list
    for row in outer_list:     # our inner loop
        li.append(row[index])  # Build the list "li" iteratively
    print li
```

If you are treating this nested list as a matrix, then what you describe is essentially taking the transpose of the matrix. You can do this entirely via list comprehensions as well:

```
outer_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

transpose = [[row[i] for row in outer_list] for i in range(len(outer_list[0]))]

print transpose
```

which yields:

```
[[1, 4, 7],
[2, 5, 8],
[3, 6, 9]]
```

As shown in the official Python tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions).

I've included the nested list comprehension example by way of completeness but a word to the wise: using nested list comprehensions generally makes code less comprehensible, not more. Just because you can doesn't mean you should.