# How can I decode list comprehension nested into dictionary?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am having trouble in understanding following code snippet:

```
_dict = {}
_dict['ut'] = {pos: [unit for unit in all_merge if pos in unit] for pos in mxn}
```

where, all_merge and mxn are lists.

I want to unroll the comprehensions for above code and want result in format like this:

```
for x in y:
   for a in b:
       if u in v:
           #do something
```

Please help me.

Comment: hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429184/converting-list-comprehensions-to-for-loops-in-python

Comment: if you understand the output & the inpui, why don't you try the loop approach yourself? otherwise why unrolling the comprehension which works?

Comment: Maybe add some sample data for clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it down step by step :

```
_dict = {}
_dict['ut'] = {pos: [unit for unit in all_merge if pos in unit] for pos in mxn}
```

To bring out the outer for loop first:

```
for pos in mxn:
    _dict{pos :[unit for unit in all_merge if pos in unit]}
```

Then to break the list comprehension:

```
temp_list = []
for unit in all_merge:
    if pos in unit:
        temp_list.append(unit)
```

Then combine them together, you can replace temp_dict with other things but just a clearer example on what's happening I guess:

```
_dict = {}
temp_dict = {}
for pos in mxn:
    temp_list = []
    for unit in all_merge:
        if pos in unit:
            temp_list.append(unit)
    temp_dict[pos] = temp_list
_dict['ut'] = temp_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

I think like this:

```
ut = {}

for pos in mxn:
    val = []
    for unit in all_merge:
        if pos in unit:
            val.append(unit)
    ut[pos] = val

_dict['ut'] = ut
```

can you provide some sample input and output?

Comment: ouch that doesn't work. `val` is initialized too deep.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you mean it should be as edited instead?

Comment: tha's better :)