# How for loop is transposing matrix in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
matrix = [
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[5, 6, 7, 8],
[9, 10, 11, 12],
]

**[[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(4)]**
```

how this loop is transposing the matrix, kindly explain in detail, if possible step after every loop.

Comment: Try using `numpy` module it has much more features for dealing with matrixes then pure Python.

Comment: This is the **exact** example in the official tutorial: [datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 2):

You unroll list comprehensions from right to left:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
          [5, 6, 7, 8],
          [9, 10, 11, 12]]

inver = [[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(4)]
```

Unrolled:

```
k = []
for i in range(4):
    l = []
    for row in matrix:
        l.append(row[i])
    k.append(l)
```

put in some print statements to figure it out. See [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and read up in [Converting List Comprehensions to For Loops in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429184/converting-list-comprehensions-to-for-loops-in-python)

As a sidenote - why come from the official tutorial pages here to get it explained? Why not also cite them?

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions

Comment: thanks patrick, i am learning from official tutorials only asked the question as i was unable to understand. I am new to stackoverflow too, didn't know how that we can directly cite out here.