# Python 3.6 converting dictionary to a sorted list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, python-3.6

I am trying to write a function in Python 3.6 that returns the content of a dictionary as a list, sorted according to the key in descending order.

Example test cases are as follows:

Inputs: `{'y':1, 'z':1, 'x':1} | {3:['x','y'], 100:['z']}`

Desired Outputs: `[{'z':1},{'y':1},{'x':1}] | [{100:['z']}, {3:['x', 'y']}]`

```
def sorted_dict_content(key_val):
    # create an empty list
    key_itemList = []
    # for each key in sorted list of keys of key_val:
    # append the key-value pair to key_itemList
    for i in key_val:
        key_itemList[key_val[i]].append(i)
        sorted(key_val.key(), reverse=True)
    return key_itemList
```

However, when I run the program I am getting IndexError: list index out of range. I also have not had luck with `sorted()`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `key_itemList[key_val[i]].append(i)`?! `key_itemList` is an empty list, but you're trying to index it with `key_val[i]` (a.k.a. retrieve the list's `key_val[i]`th element), which isn't possible since `key_itemList` is _empty_.

Comment: You used a list element as an index into the same list; you also tried to assign to a non-existent location in your empty list.

Comment: here is a function that does what you want: `def f(D):
    return [{k: D[k]} for k in sorted(D.keys(), reverse=True)]`

Comment: ^Similar to grant just use `.items()`: `[{key: val} for key, val in sorted(dic.items(), reverse=True)]`

Comment: @Prune this doesnt seem like a duplicate at all to the question linked. Its taking a dictionary of many key values pairs and returning  a list of single key value pair dictionaries sorted by by the key in descending order.

Comment: @GrantWilliams thanks! Is there a way I can solve this by creating an empty list, appending the key-value pairs to this list, and returning it so I can pass that list through another function?

Comment: @markellefultz20 you can do the same approach i suggested or the one Syntactical Remorse suggested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429184/converting-list-comprehensions-to-for-loops-in-python Shows you how to convert a comprehension to a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Trying to assign to the list via `list[something] = something else` will try to acces the list at the `something`-index not extend the list by adding the `something`-index, unlike a dict's behaviour. The correct way to append the key-value-pair to the list would be

```
key_ItemList.append({key_val[i]:i})
```