# Convert a nested list-comprehension to regular for loops

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to know how to write this list-comprehension with regular loops:

```
sep_class = [[x for x, t in zip(X_train, y_train) if t==c] for c in np.unique(y_train)]
```

I tried it this way:

```
sep_class = []
for c in np.unique(y_train):
    for x, t in zip(X_train, y_train):
        if t == c:
            sep_class.append(x)
```

But the outputs are different. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes they should be, aside from the fact that sep is not defined.

Comment: Please read https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Comment: This list comprehension is creating a list with sublists, while the other code seems to append everything to the same list.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I was trying to ask how to decompose the list comperhension that I have but never mind I saw Karl Knechtel's link and figured it out.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429184/converting-list-comprehensions-to-for-loops-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general way of converting a list-comprehension to regular loops is as follows:

```py
l = [f(x) for x in iter]

# converts to:

l = []
for x in iter:
    l.append(f(x))
```

When you have nested list creation in the comprehension this gets a little more complicated but follows the same logic, now `f(x)` is a translation of list-comp itself. So we have:

```py
l = [[g(x) for x in sub] for sub in iter]

# converts to:

l = []
for sub in iter:
    temp = []
    for x in sub:
        temp.append(g(x))
    l.append(temp)
```

So in your case, simply adding the condition, the list-comp becomes:

```py
sep_class = [[x for x, t in zip(X_train, y_train)if t ==c] for c in np.unique(y_train)]

# converts to:

sep_class = []
for c in np.unique(y_train):
    sub = []
    for x, t in zip(X_train, y_train):
        if t == c:
            sub.append(x)
    sep_class.append(sub)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sep_class = []
for c in np.unique(y_train):
    sep_class.append([])
    for x, t in zip(X_train, y_train):
        if t ==c:
            sep_class[c].append(x)
```

now they are identical.

Comment: But that assumes that `c` behaves like `for c in range(...)`... What if `c` is `2` on the first iteration?

Comment: @Tomerikoo never thought anout this...but you re right, as my unique(y_train) is just (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) so this works in my case. Anyway it is a bad question, and I figured it out. Thank you.

Comment: Actually it is not a bad question at all! I couldn't find anything similar on the site and just today encountered a similar question. So this is actually a good question that can help others - you just might have asked it wrong... See my edit for your question and see my answer with more explanations