# Guys, can someone give a hand how could I change this to a For loop, please?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples, list-comprehension

```
MyList = [tuple(i for i in j if type(i) != str ) for j in MyList]
```

result is a tuple inside list, for example:

```
[(X,Y), (X2,Y2)]
```

Comment: Why do you want to change it into a for loop?

Comment: What different result do you want from a for loop?

Comment: Can you share `MyList`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting List Comprehensions to For Loops in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429184/converting-list-comprehensions-to-for-loops-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

What is relevant here is understanding [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which you want to reverse.

This sounds to me like some form of course homework to make sure you understand what's going on in that line ;-)

```
MyList = [(1,2,3,(1,2), "hello world"),("hello"),(3,4,1),"world"]

comp = [tuple(i for i in j if type(i) != str ) for j in MyList] 
print(comp)

newList = []
for j in MyList:
    newTup = []
    for i in j:
        if type(i) is not str:
            newTup.append(i)
    newList.append(tuple(newTup))
print(newList)

fun = list(map(lambda j: tuple(filter(lambda i: type(i) is not str,j)) , MyList))
print(fun)
```